# Get an argument to take more than one value - R

Tags: r, function, vector, arguments

So I am creating mapping function which plots with points the coordinates of various ports. I want to create a function that allows users to select which of the ports they want to label and then alter the label position.

Here are the various ports and their coordinates:

```
           Labels       Lon      Lat
1     Halifax, NS -63.59341 44.68068
2  St. John's, NL -52.73304 47.59341
3  Saint John, NB -66.05236 45.27925
4    Portland, ME -70.24435 43.68068
5  Woods Hole, MA -70.68068 41.62832
6 Nuuk, Greenland -51.75049 64.17453
7      Boston, MA -71.08727 42.36652
```

And my function:

```
    port.label <- function (pos1, cex1 = 0.6, offset1 = 0.2, col1 = "deeppink") {
      port.file<-read.csv("V:/Science/Finalised Map Files/Ports.csv")
      Lon <- port.file$Lon
      Lat <- port.file$Lat
      Lab <- paste(port.file$Lab) 
      a <- locator()
      ay <- unlist(a[2])
      aylab <- sapply (ay, function (x) which.min (abs (x - Lat)))
      b <- for (i in (1:length (aylab))) {
        text (x = Lon [aylab[i]], y = Lat [aylab[i]], labels = Lab [aylab[i]],
        pos = pos1, cex = cex1, offset = offset1, col = col1) 
      }
    }
```

Now when I try to run it with: `port.label(pos1=c(1,2,3,4))` after clicking on four points it returns the labels using only the first value (1), so below the point. So it is only taking the first value. I tried pre-setting the pos1 length to be related to the number of ports clicked on, but this didn't help either.

Any ideas on why it will only take the first pos1 value rather than the whole vector?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a look to the help of the identify function? maybe it could help you

Comment: I thought about identify, but doesn't it just plot the labels relative to where you clicked rather than you being able to set the position of the label

Answer (score 1):

Um, because for each call of text() you are calling it with the full vector. Since each call is for one label only, you need to call it with `pos=pos1[i]`. Unfortunately, then calling port.label with only 1 argument would require additional checking of pos1() length. Say, you want to have all labels at the same position, bottom, so you call `port.label( pos1= 1 )`. With `i=2`, `pos1[i]` will take the value `NA`. Therefore, you will have to expand `pos1` if its length is equal to 1.

It would be more efficient to call it like that:

```
port.label <- function (pos1, cex1 = 0.6, offset1 = 0.2, col1 = "deeppink") {
  port.file<-read.csv("V:/Science/Finalised Map Files/Ports.csv")
  Lon <- port.file$Lon
  Lat <- port.file$Lat
  Lab <- paste(port.file$Lab) 
  a <- locator()
  ay <- unlist(a[2])
  aylab <- sapply (ay, function (x) which.min (abs (x - Lat)))
  text( x= Lon[aylab], y= Lat[aylab], labels= Lab[aylab], 
        pos= pos1, cex= cex1, offset= offset1, col= col1 )
}
```

Comment: I only skimmed the code but I don't see why there would need to be additional checking if you made the change suggested.  Also in your code you have `po1` instead of `pos1`

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful to use `dput` to output your data in a form that easier for readers to run in R.

```
mydat <- structure(list(Lab = c("Halifax, NS", "St. John's, NL", "Saint John, NB", 
    "Portland, ME", "Woods Hole, MA", "Nuuk, Greenland", "Boston, MA"), 
    Lon = c(-63.59341, -52.73304, -66.05236, -70.24435, -70.68068, -51.75049, -71.08727), 
    Lat = c(44.68068, 47.59341, 45.27925, 43.68068, 41.62832, 64.17453, 42.36652)), 
    .Names = c("Labels", "Lon", "Lat"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

It's not at all clear to me why you would want a function that does this.  I'm thinking there may be a better way to do what you really want to do.  But, here is an attempt to modify your code so that it does what you want.  I made use of the `identify()` function as @droopy suggested.

```
port.label <- function (data, posn, cex1=0.6, offset1=0.2, col1="deeppink") {
    j <- identify(mydat$Lon, mydat$Lat, mydat$Lab, plot=FALSE)
    for(i in 1:length(j)) {
        text(x=data$Lon[j[i]], y=data$Lat[j[i]], labels=data$Lab[j[i]], pos=posn[i], cex=cex1, offset=offset1, col=col1)
        }
    }

plot(mydat$Lon, mydat$Lat)
port.label(mydat, posn=c(1, 2, 3, 4))
```